# How do I run a scheduled job in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql, cron

I have a Django app which have invitations stored in a db (mysql for now, but may go Postgres). These invitations have expiration dates. I want the invitation removed from the database when the expiration date arrives. I want this done from the Django side as opposed to directly from the database because I need the proper notifications / cleanup to occur which the app handles. I guess I could do have a cron job run every once in a while and have it hit the API but I really wanted to have all app components within the app and not rely on OS function (cron).

Comment: Check this: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: @ChristosAmanatidis -- thanks. that might work. i'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cron *is* the correct way to run scheduled jobs. That's the fundamental philosophy of unix-like systems: components that know how to do a single thing well, and cron is the thing that knows how to trigger jobs at a certain time.

In terms of what the job itself should be, the easiest thing is to write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a web service which, when hit, does what I need it to do. I'll schedule a cron job to throw an http request at it periodically.